# put google map into the listview every item

Tags: android, google-maps

This problem preplexs me a few days.I want to put google map into the listview.

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if(convertView == null){
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mlayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mapcontent, null);
                viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                mapView = (MapView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.map);
                mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                if (aMap == null) {
                    aMap = mapView.getMap();
                }
```

Comment: Does the code work? What errors are you getting?  We might need more info

Comment: It does not work.I do not know how to write xml,and I want to know if google map would show in every item in listview.Thanks in advance.if you know could you please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: @Ethan  I dont think so that MapView is Working anymore as according to Google Map API V2. You have to use Mapfragment or supportMapFragment to show Map.

Comment: @Balvinder I do it like you said but it does not work